# Special Prices showing not matter what

Tags: magento-1.9, pricing

The problem is that the special prices are showing in case they are actually filled for a specific product. The dates are set correctly, meaning the date on which is tested is outside the period that should activate the special price. Caches have been cleared, index reindexed (multiple times) etc etc. All without any positive result. A while ago the hosting company activated HHVM on the server but due to several problems this was deactivated a couple of weeks back. Could this still have some effect on the special prices still showing? Or should I look in a entirely different direction?

Magento version 1.9.0.1 BTW

Comment: If you have multiple site may be price are updated for different site please this may storeview or website issue.

Comment: You are absolutely right! That is in fact the problem which we overlooked... Thanks!

Comment: I have added it as answer please accept answer and would be great if get up vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may causing because you may have multiple site or storeview and product values are updated for specific sites or storeview please check and it will resolve your issue.